# Azure Kubernetes Service clusters should have Defender profile enabled

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I am trying to fix this high severity error for Azure Kubernetes Cluster

I tried using Azure portal but It keeps spinning for hours and does not fix it.

I also tried with below Az Command -

```
az aks update --enable-defender --resource-group <your-resource-group> --name <your-cluster-name>
```

but it gives error -

unrecognized arguments: --enable-defender az

I am looking for guidance to fix this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that your `az aks` command is too old. Update with `sudo apt-get update` or similar or install a new version from scratch. The client is updated frequently so it is not uncommon to run into features not supported with an old version.

Answer (score 5):

Have you registered the defender feature prior to running the update command?

```
az feature register --namespace Microsoft.ContainerService --name AKS-AzureDefender
```